# Definir cores no Google Geochart Laravel?

Tags: mysql, json, laravel, google-charts

Eu estou tentando definir as cores dos estados brasileiros, que estão vindo do mysql via **json** as informações, mas não estou tendo resultado no retorno das cores. 
Ex.:

> São Paulo na cor Azul - 
>   Minas Gerais na cor Verde - 
>   Rio Grande do Sul na cor Vermelha

e assim por diante, como posso definir essas cores? Visto que estou fazendo da seguinte maneira:

```
colorAxis: {colors: ['#00853f', 'black', '#e31b23']},
backgroundColor: '#81d4fa',
datalessRegionColor: '#f8bbd0',
defaultColor: '#f5f5f5',
```

**JSON**

```
 $estados = Estados::selectRaw('SUM(valor) as valor, estado as estado')->groupBy('estado')->get();

    $arrayEstados[] = ['Estado', 'Valor'];

    foreach($estados as $key => $valor) {
        $arrayEstados[++$key] = [$valor->estado, $valor->valor]; 
    }

    dd($arrayEstados);

    return view('home', compact('notasEntrada', 'notasSaida', 'valorNotasEntrada', 'valorNotasSaida'))->with('nome', json_encode($array))->with('estados', json_encode($arrayEstados));
```

[print do retorno JSON](https://prnt.sc/mmso1b)

sendo que assim, não estou controlando as cores dos estados.

Obrigado desde já

Comment: Você ta utilizando a biblioteca Lavacharts?

Comment: Não estou usando nenhuma biblioteca @sant0will

Comment: Sim, está usando a API Google Chart né

Comment: Ah sim... somente ela! @sant0will

Comment: como está seu json? edite a pergunta e coloque ele

Comment: pronto @sant0will editada a pergunta com o JSON e o retorno dele

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89896/discussion-between-sant0will-and-cristiano-facirolli).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para teste foi usada a `string(json)` já com os valores.

A página receberá a `string(json)` do `controller` na variável tratada como `$estados` no código.
Como você recebe um `json` na página, é necessário passar o conteúdo para uma array. Basta passar a array para a função da API.

Para adicionar as cores é necessário fazer as configurações no `options` com :

```
colorAxis:{
    colors:['red','green','blue'],
    minValue: 1,
    maxValue: 210
},
```

A forma que a api funciona é a seguinte: As cores são colocadas em forma de degrade colocando a primeira cor da configuração('red') para o menor valor e a ultima(no caso 'blue') para o maior.

Exemplo funcionando:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["geochart"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

        function drawRegionsMap() {
            let json = '[{"nome":"Distrito Federal","valor":100}, {"nome":"Goiás","valor":50}, {"nome":"Paraiba","valor":30}, {"nome":"Rio de Janeiro","valor":20}, {"nome":"Rio Grande do Sul","valor":1}, {"nome":"São Paulo","valor":210}]';

            // let estados = JSON.parse('<?php echo $estados ?>'); //seu caso
            let estados = JSON.parse(json); //teste
            let arr_estados = new Array();
            arr_estados.push(['Estado', 'Valor']);

            for (var k in estados) {
                arr_estados.push([estados[k].nome, estados[k].valor]);
            }

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arr_estados);

            var options = {
                region:'BR',
                displayMode: 'auto',
                resolution:'provinces',
                colorAxis:{
                    colors:['red','green','blue'],
                    minValue: 1,
                    maxValue: 210
                },
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="regions_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Discussão para solucionar](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89896/discussion-between-sant0will-and-cristiano-facirolli)